# cant run unit test using karma/jasmine - “Incomplete: No specs found” in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, protractor

For some reason I can't understand, Karma says that Jasmine can't find any of my test specs. I'm using Angular 10, Typescript and ng test to run the tests,

i believe i have configuration error somewhere
(in the past it worked, it suddenly stop working).

in network i get 404 from `main.json`

in ide i get this message:

```
 TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
 TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
 TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
```

on chrome:

```
Karma v5.0.9 - connected
Incomplete: No specs found, , randomized with seed 77127
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/gravity-fe'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "gravity-fe": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/gravity-fe",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss",
              "src/styles/theme.scss",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/quill-mention/dist/quill.mention.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "graphql-tag",
              "zen-observable",
              "hammerjs"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "12kb",
                  "maximumError": "16kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "demo": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.demo.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "gravity-fe:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "gravity-fe:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "gravity-fe:build:development"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "gravity-fe:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "gravity-fe:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "gravity-fe:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "gravity-fe"
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
 {
      "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
        "types": [
          "jasmine"
        ]
      },
      "files": [
        "src/test.ts",
        "src/polyfills.ts"
      ],
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.spec.ts",
        "src/**/*.d.ts"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: If it suddenly stopped, what was the last change you made? If you undo it (e.g. stash your current changes), do the tests run again?

Comment: i dunno, i havent work on this project before.

Comment: But you say it worked in the past, how do you know? Have people not been running the tests on each commit?